# Exporting files from mongodb

Tags: mongodb, export

I have around 1500 files in a mongodb file storage. I need to export them, and I am using this script to do it:

```
#!/bin/bash
_prefix="${1:?Usage: file prefix to export db}"
while read -r line; do
    file=$(echo "$line" | awk -F'\t' '{ print $1 }')
    [[ $file == 'connected to'* ]] && continue
    mkdir -p $_prefix
    mongofiles  -h localhost -d **DB_NAME** --prefix="$_prefix" get "$file"
done < <(mongofiles  -h localhost -d **DB_NAME** --prefix="$_prefix" list)
```

So heres the problem. A lot of the files have the same name, for example img.jpeg.

I need to be able to rename them but still keeping track of what db entity it belongs to. I'm thinking something like the md5 hash, but I'm not sure how to get that from the exact file I'm exporting.

Anyone have any experience or tips for doing this?